# Why is my DNS server not forwarding?

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, bind

I have setup bind like this:

```
//
// named.conf
//
// Provided by Red Hat bind package to configure the ISC BIND named(8) DNS
// server as a caching only nameserver (as a localhost DNS resolver only).
//
// See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/ for example named configuration files.
//

options {
        listen-on port 53 { any; };
#       listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        forwarders      { 10.90.0.135; 10.90.0.174; };
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        allow-query     { any; };
        recursion yes;

        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;
        dnssec-lookaside auto;

        /* Path to ISC DLV key */
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";


zone "appletop.local" IN {
        type master;
        file "appletop.local";
        allow-update { none; };
};
```

But it doesn't forward?

If I just put the DNS server address into `resolv.conf` on another machine I get the correct lookups so the DNS server must be able to resolve for me but if I then point the other machine back at this one it cannot resolve the names.

What's wrong?

---

**After changes suggested by MadHatter:**

Now it starts but hangs on a dig +trace and doesn't forward - why do I not see the forwarders addresses below?

```
[root@ns1 ~]# ping www.yahoo.com
^C
[root@ns1 ~]# cd /etc/
[root@ns1 etc]# cp named.conf named.conf.last
[root@ns1 etc]# vi named.conf
[root@ns1 etc]# /etc/init.d/named reload
Reloading named-sdb:                                       [  OK  ]
[root@ns1 etc]# service named stop
Stopping named: .                                          [  OK  ]
[root@ns1 etc]# /etc/init.d/named start
Starting named:                                            [  OK  ]
[root@ns1 etc]# nslookup www.yahoo.com
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
Server:         10.138.10.30
Address:        10.138.10.30#53

** server can't find www.yahoo.com: NXDOMAIN
```

And a dig with +trace:

```
[root@ns1 etc]# dig +trace www.yahoo.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.17.rc1.0.2.el6_4.6 <<>> +trace www.yahoo.com
;; global options: +cmd
.                       518400  IN      NS      E.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       518400  IN      NS      M.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       518400  IN      NS      I.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       518400  IN      NS      F.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       518400  IN      NS      G.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       518400  IN      NS      K.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       518400  IN      NS      B.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       518400  IN      NS      A.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       518400  IN      NS      C.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       518400  IN      NS      L.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       518400  IN      NS      J.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       518400  IN      NS      H.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       518400  IN      NS      D.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
```

My entire file looks like this now - whats wrong?

```
 options {
         listen-on port 53 { any; };
 #       listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
         directory       "/var/named";
         dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
         statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
         memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
         allow-query     { any; };
         recursion yes;

         dnssec-enable yes;
         dnssec-validation yes;
         dnssec-lookaside auto;

         /* Path to ISC DLV key */
         bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

         managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic"; };

 logging {
         channel default_debug {
                 file "data/named.run";
                 severity dynamic;
         }; };

 zone "." IN {
         type forward;
         forward first;
         forwarders { 10.90.0.135;
                      10.90.0.174;
                    } ; };

 include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones"; include "/etc/named.root.key";


 zone "appletop.local" IN {
         type master;
         file "appletop.local";
         allow-update { none; }; };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've told it what forwarders to use, but not when to use them.  If you want it to use them for everything, instead of

```
zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};
```

try

```
zone "." {
        type forward;
        forward first;
        forwarders { 10.90.0.135;
                     10.90.0.174;
                   } ;
} ;
```

**Edit**: OK, try the above instead.  I don't get what you mean by "try to resolve locally first", though; you said you wanted it to forward.

Comment: thanks but id like it to try to resolve locally before going to the forwarder - wont 'first' stop that?

Comment: OK i tried what you said but now its broken it says:
Error in named configuration:
/etc/named.conf:40: no matching 'forwarders' statement

Comment: ok now it starts but doesnt forward - why do i not see the forwarder addresses in the below:

Comment: still not working what was your edit ladadadada?

Comment: problem was dnssec

Answer (score 4):

In my case the problem was solved by only changing `dnssec-validation yes;` to `dnssec-validation no;`

Answer (score 2):

Just in case it wasn't clear by the OP's comment below MadHatter's respond, "problem was dnssec", I'm posting this answer explicitly since I too found it solved my problem.

I've setup a caching, forwarding-only BIND server and it wasn't forwarding. The queries were going to the root server with a several-second-delay. Disabling the dnssec options fix this, now it is working as expected.

```
dnssec-enable no;
dnssec-validation no;
dnssec-lookaside auto;
```

Comment: This worked for me too. 1) it looks my dns in local cache 2) if local cache fail it looks for internet